# elasticsearch dsl python : how to search by value inside array

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I have the following structure in my index:

```
[
    {
         name:"project1",
         users: [
                   {"id":"1"},
                   {"id":"2"}
         ]
    },
    #... more projects
]
```

I would like to know how can I get all projects of a specific user (by his id), here is what I have tried :

```
q = Q("term", id="1") 
resp = projects_index.query("nested",path="users",query=q).execute()
```

but I get no result, what am I missing ?
  Thank you
Edit : 
here is my index mapping :

```
   {
      "projects": {
        "mappings": {
          "doc": {
            "properties": {
              "created_at": {
                "type": "date"
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "users": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                  "id": {
                    "type": "text"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Add the mapping of index, so that people can help you better.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm not sure what you mean by the mapping index ? I have given an example of a document (or array of documents), each filed project (document) has a name and a list of users

Comment: Use this to get mapping: `GET /<index>/_mapping`. Replace `<index>` with your index name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are not getting results is because while specifying a nested path you should provide the full name including parent field name i.e. you should use `users.id` instead of just `id`. The query thus will translate to as below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "users",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "users.id": "1"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Suggestion:** Change the type of `id` field to `keyword`, to prevent id value getting tokenism into multiple terms.

Comment: thank you ! for python eleasticsearch dsl syntax it's :  __ instead of . :
Q("term", users__id="id_looking_for")